# Website shows blank white screen solely on Windows IE11

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-11

www.relius.de works fine in any browser as far as I know. Windows IE11 however shows a blank white page. I have no idea what the problem could be. Can somebody help?

- IE11 Addons deactivated
- IE11 reset
- Tried different sub-sites, not only home
- Problem shows on different computers at different locations (Tried 3 totally different users, in totally different cities)

Answer (score 0):

I try to check the site and find that your site is showing an error in the console and keep trying to loading.

[image]

I try to search regarding this error and find that in 2016 there is some issue with the IE 11. Microsoft had confirmed the issue and informed users to install the [MS16-104: Security update for Internet Explorer: September 13, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3185319/ms16-104-security-update-for-internet-explorer-september-13-2016)

Reference:

["Permission Denied" script error in Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191336/permission-denied-script-error-in-internet-explorer-11)

But this is the old update. so if you are using any older version than you can try to install this update to see whether it fix the issue or not.

If you are using the latest updates for your Windows OS and IE browser than it can be possible that issue is something else.

If you are not the developer of this site than you need to contact the developers of this site and inform them about this issue. They can try to look in to it to see what is causing this issue.

We need the problematic code. Without code, we are not able to guess what is causing this issue.

Comment: Hello Deepak, thanks for your help. We have been able to identify the problematic script. For anyone experiencing the same issue: It was the GDPR Cookie Consent Plugin for Wordpress. It seems like there is a bug in the plugin. Will post further information as soon as I get an answer from tech support.